# Cannot compile 3D point viewer in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, opengl

Can someone help me ?I am trying to run the 3d point cloud viewer .However it shows me the following errors

```
Error   1   error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'    c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'glAccum' c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   4   error C2182: 'APIENTRY' : illegal use of type 'void'    c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   6   error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'    c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1153    Viewer
Error   7   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1153    Viewer
```

and so on ...
Beginning of my code is :

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <GL/glut.h>

    #include <cmath>
    #include "arcball.h"
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
 using namespace std;
```

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first reported error is on the first line that declares a function with the `WINGDIAPI` modifier. Apparently, this is declared in `wingdi.h`. However, I'm not sure if you're meant to `#include` that directly, or whether there's a more formal recommendation for compiling opengl code in the windows environment. I'll have a hunt around.

The page on MSDN discussing the [necessary headers for OpenGL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374218%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) work are a bit vague, but I take:

> The Windows functions that support Microsoft's implementation of OpenGL in Windows must include the header file Windows.h.

To mean that you ought to include `windows.h` first.

---

Really? If I create a blank C++ project in VS2008, create an empty cpp file, copy and paste your includes in, and hit compile, I get exactly the errors you described. If I change my includes to:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <cmath>
#include "arcball.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

Then the first reported error I get is that it can't find "arcball.h" (hardly unexpected). Are you still getting the same errors once windows.h is included?

Comment: added include <windows.h>...doesnt help.

Comment: -Yes i still get that .Notice I 'include <GL/glut.h> 'whereas you  'include <GL/gl.h>'.Try running it with this.And btw I did try what you did with creating a new empty project.It did compile but then again as I pointed our include files are different.

Comment: @Manish - my `v6.0A\Include\GL` directory only has `gl.h` and `glu.h`. But given the reported errors were in the `gl.h` header, I thought I was being close enough. Where has the `glut.h` header come from?